# Is animating a small image contained in a CSS sprite as efficient as animating just that image?

Tags: css, performance, image, load, sprite

I'm about to go through my CSS and compile images into sprites, and I'm wondering what will be the most efficient approach. Currently, I've got a bunch of tiny, ~10x10 px images that need to be animated. I'm wondering if adding these images to a sprite with much larger dimensions (~1000x1000px), and then animating them will cause any difference in CPU load/performance. It's the difference between animating a small div or animating a giant div where only a small part (the specified background position) is visible.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to animate a sprite.

1 server request for all images and once it is cached it's no problem.

What I would take care is the ammount of animation effects you intend to put in since doing to much could result in running slow (specially css3 3d transforms).

Have you thought of using `canvas` for animation instead of a container div?

Comment: I haven't looked into any canvas stuff... the project is an ebook in the browser with tons of animated images. I'm using CSS transforms.

Answer (score 0):

An animated GIF is handled at a lower level than JavaScript, even if you're just swapping class names. Animated GIFs don't suffer from garbage collection delays and take less overhead.

Go with the animated GIF over the sprite. The file size won't differ much anyway.

Comment: Good idea - but works only in case you can afford to use a .gif